# .htaccess rewrite @username and @username/photos

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

hi guys i am trying to rewrite a url but getting errors

i would like to rewrite

```
www.example.com/photos.php?u=username
```

to

```
www.example.com/@username/photos
```

here is my code

```
IndexIgnore *

RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks


RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^@([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ user.php?u=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^@([A-Za-z0-9]+)$/^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ user.php?u=$1  photos.php?u=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first `RewriteRule` looks fine, but your second `RewriteRule` is full of errors.

1. You're trying to feed the right hand of the rule with 2 different address as seen at:

   ```
   user.php?u=$1  photos.php?u=$1
   ```
2. Your rule on the left hand have a terminator sign at the middle of the regex and after it you start a new regex which would not work as well:

   ```
   ^@([A-Za-z0-9]+)$/^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$
   ```

This should work for your needs and it should be placed inside your `.htaccess` file, which should be located inside your domain ROOT folder along with both the `photos.php` and the `user.php` files or it will not work.

```
IndexIgnore *

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/photos$ photos.php?u=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ user.php?u=$1 [QSA,L]
```

If you have a different folder setup then update your question with more information on it so I can update the rule to fit it.

The above rules will allow you to access the photo page in the following format:

```
www.example.com/@username/photos
```

And the users page in the following format:

```
www.example.com/@username
```

Comment: +1 very well explained, OP may want to use `QSA` flag as well.

Comment: It worked like a charm only when i go to [link]www.example.com/@username/photos[/link] the css and images do not display so i must update my css code links in my html aswell? css and iimages is in a different folder. user.php and photos.php in root folder css and photos are in separate folders

Comment: @ZoneBuddy yes you need to update the URL of your CSS and images or use the HTML tag base. For example `<base href="http://example.com/" />`. [Kindly check my answer as the accepted answer since you said it solved your problem, see here how.](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)